# JMeter thread group - creating a UI and automating the process

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

For our mobile app we have a NoSQL database and we use Jmeter to load the data to the database (generate documents and post). For different types of entities we have different types of thread groups in jmeter. The problem here is each thread group we have to run manually and wait until it ends and run the next thread group. Each thread group lasts in different times depending on the contexts.

We have an idea to automate this process to make a user interface so the whole process starts with a one button and with some minimum configurations. But we do not know whether

> it is possible?
>   if so how to commence?

Can anyone shed some light on this and let me know the answers to the above questions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to write a batch file or shell file and start your jmeter test from cammand line ( [Hot to start the jmeter test from command line](https://blog.e-zest.com/how-to-run-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/))

```
jmeter -n –t test.jmx -l testresults.jtl
```

Use different test for each scenario. A batch file will execute the tests in desired order. Your can configure tasks for windows or us cron for unix OS. I think it is the easiest way tom "automate" your test start.

You also can check [other ways to start JMeter without GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! I will try this out!

Comment: You're welcome. Did it work for you? Which way did you choose?